# Trying to log in to Amazon Vendor Central with python requests

Tags: python, forms, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to log in to Amazon Vendor Central using the following form:

```
<form action="/ap/widget" id="loginForm" method="POST" name="loginForm" style="display: inline">
 <input name="widgetToken" type="hidden" value="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:N2hJTk9lOGhlb0hCNC8rZ3Jybi9vKys3czRlcFVRU2l2RXg4alBwU2tUaz06MQ=="/>
 <table border="0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="tiny label" nowrap="true">
     E-mail:
    </td>
    <td class="tiny paddedLeft" nowrap="true">
     <input class="textField " id="username" maxlength="64" name="username" size="25" style=" font-size: 10px" type="text" value=""/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tiny label paddedTop" nowrap="true">
     Password:
    </td>
    <td class="tiny paddedTop paddedLeft" nowrap="true">
     <input class="textField" id="password" maxlength="30" name="password" size="25" style=" font-size: 10px" type="password" value=""/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td class="tiny paddedTop paddedLeft">
     <button class="sprite-button-wrap" id="login-button-container" type="submit">
      <span class="sprite-button sprite-small small-yellow-primary sprite-primary ">
       Sign in
       <span class="sprite-button-end">
       </span>
      </span>
     </button>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td class="tiny paddedTop paddedLeft">
     <a href="https://vendorcentral.amazon.com/gp/vendor/passreset/start/134-0595492-6046235">
      Forgot your password?
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

This is how I went about it:

```
s=requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r=s.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

print r.url
form = soup.find(id='loginForm')
token = form.find_all('input')[0]['value']

login_data={"widgetToken":token,
"username":USERNAME,
"password":PASSWORD}

r = s.post(URL, login_data)
print r.url # Should be the page that the login redirects to.
```

Running this code results in two identical urls being printed, meaning it didn't even attempt to login. (A failed login attempt would go to a different url, just not the one I want.) How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you should submit the post data to `https://vendorcentral.amazon.com/ap/widget`

Comment: That resulted in

    `https://vendorcentral.amazon.com/gp/vendor/sign-in  
    https://vendorcentral.amazon.com/ap/widget` 

as output. So that didn't work.